# Hashtable alternatives

Tags: java, hashtable

Are there any alternatives to using hash tables?
I have this code and was wondering if I could make do without using it. What I have is working find, but I've been told not to use it by some people. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Cart
{ 

public Hashtable items = new Hashtable();


public Enumeration getEnumeration()
{
return items.elements();
}


public void addItem(String itemId,String desc, float price, int quantity)
{
String[] item = {itemId, desc, Float.toString(price),
Integer.toString(quantity)};

if (items.containsKey(itemId))
{

  String[] tmpItem = (String[])items.get(itemId);
  int tmpQuant = Integer.parseInt(tmpItem[3]);
  quantity += tmpQuant;
  tmpItem[3] = Integer.toString(quantity);
}
else {

  items.put(itemId, item);
 }
}


public float getTotalCost() {

Enumeration e = items.elements();
String[] tmpItem;
float totalCost = 0.00f;

while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

  tmpItem = (String[])e.nextElement();
  totalCost += (Integer.parseInt(tmpItem[3]) *
    Float.parseFloat(tmpItem[2]));
}
return totalCost;
}

}
```

Comment: Is your code supposed to run cuncurrently? i.e. from multiple threads?

Answer (score 2):

`Hashtable` is synchronized and that could cause performance issues, that's why you're advised to use something like a `HashMap` or any other suitable class that implements `Map`.

Actually, if you changed your code to use a `Map` you wouldn't have mayor problems (actually `Hashmap` itself implements `Map`).

Comment: Probably a `Map` backed by `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to **find** an item  with the `itemId` the best data structure would be `HashMap` because of access time.
but if you items are **sorted** according to the `itemId`, you can use other data structures as `arraylist` or `array` or even making your own class with four public variables.
but i say once a gain for **searching** the best DS would be `hashMap`